# Symfony2 + FOSCommentBundle: redirection in a new page after savng new comment

Tags: symfony

I use `FOSCommentBundle` with `Symfony2` and when I save a new comment it redirect me to another page.

So my question is how can I do to stay in the same page. What is the `class or method` I have to `reimplement`?

Thanks for all

Sam

Comment: I have found the solution. I have to include the jqery.form.js pllugin. Hope this help people... See ya Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. I have to include the jquery.form.js pllugin. Hope this help people... See ya

Sam